# The difference between 困る and 困った in this sentence

Tags: grammar, tense

This is a multiple choice question and the correct answer seems to be 困った, but I wonder why 困る is not right.

The sentence is as follows
しまった!財布を忘れてきた。(困る/困った)なあ。

I do think Japanese tense can be quite confusing sometimes. I'll appreciate it if you can explain this to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

困った would be correct because the action happened already. There's *already* trouble so past tense.

It'd be easy to make a case where both are correct though.

Comment: So 困った means something like "I'm troubled by something that happened in the past", not "I was troubled by something", is that right?

Comment: This kind of explanation is tricky in Japanese because there's no release tense for the present, the past, nor the future. It's rather just two states: accomplished or not. Those two states can be in the past, the present, etc.
In this context 困ったな is hard to translate in english but rather than saying "I am trouble", it's rather the situation which got [more] difficult. If the text was using 困るな it would be something like "Troubles are coming" kind of thing.